# time complexity of iteration in python

Tags: python, iterator, time-complexity

I have a question about iterating through a list in python.
Let's say I have lists A = [1, 2, 3, 4] and B = []. What is the difference (if any) between using these two cycles? I'm intrested in the time complexity.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    B.append(A[i])

for i in A:
    B.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The time-complexity is **identical** for both of those operations loops.

Think about it this way:

> How many iterations will they have to do?

They'll both have to do `len(A)` number of loops. So therefore, they will take the same length of time.

---

Another way that this may be written is `O(n)`. This is an example of [`Big-O-Notation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and just means that the time-complexity is `linear` - i.e both of the operations will take the same amount of time longer if the list goes from being length `5 --> 10` as it would if the list went from being length `1000 --> 1005`.

--

The other time-complexities can be seen clearly in the following grap which was stolen from this great [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517541/7434365) in another answer:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

Each loop is `O(n)`, or linear time:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    B.append(A[i])

for i in A:
    B.append(i)
```

Each `append` operation is `O(1)`, and the indexing occurring at `B.append(A[i])` is also `O(1)`. Thus, the overall time complexity for this code block is:

```
T(N) = O(n) + O(n) = 2*O(n) => O(n)
```

since Big - O measures worst case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093097/time-complexity-of-finding-the-length-of-an-array) question/answer, len(A) has a time-complexity of O(1), so it doesn't increase the complexity of the first loop that you mentioned. Both possibilities have to do n cycles, where n is the length of A. 
All in all, both possibilities have a time-complexity of O(n).